# Python: resample on a rolling basis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, pandas-resample

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
data = [[99330,12,122],
   [1123,1230,1287],
   [123,101,812739],
   [1143,12301230,252],
   [234,342,4546],
   [2445,3453,3457],
   [7897,8657,5675],
   [46,5675,453],
   [76,484,3735],
   [363,93,4568],
   [385,568,367],
   [458,846,4847],
   [574,45747,658468],
   [57457,46534,4675]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04',
                           '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-08',
                           '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12',
                           '2022-01-13', '2022-01-14'], 
              columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df1.resample('1D').last().rolling(7).last()
```

The last line gives me the following error: `AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'last'`

What I want to do is resample the data on a rolling basis (for 7, 30, 90 days).

Is there a way to this without using many loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply `last` as if `rolling` gave you dataframe; it doesn't (because it's actually "incomplete" as you can see below).

A general tip is that you can grab whatever you get from the previous step, and use `help` on it.
In this case

```py
x = df1.resample('1D').last().rolling(7)
help(x)
```

which gives you a very extensive manual.

What's missing from your problem is that you haven't actually precisely specified *what* you want to roll. Do you want a rolling *mean*?
That gives you a hint that you want to use `.mean()` on the rolled data.

More specifically, in this case, it's probably most helpful to use the timedelta, which will make the code even more clear, and help you with corner-cases as opposed to using the integer count

```py
rolled_df = df1.rolling(datetime.timedelta(days=7)).mean()
```